# HTML refuses to include Javascript [UIWebView]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

What's the deal?  I am trying to animate a color property, so I have jQuery 1.7.1 and the jquery color plugin from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).  The files are all included and I verified that they are members of the build target, so they are all getting copied.  Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content" class="changesColor" contenteditable="false" style="font-family:New Century Schoolbook; font-size:20; color:black; line-height:200%">
        ...Content...
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.color.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="textOps.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I edited it for brevity, but this is the structure.  None of my animate calls to color properties work.  ***HOWEVER***, If I copy the content of jquery.color.js and paste it into the bottom of jQuery.js then it works just fine.  What is causing this file to not load (it is not just this file either...it seems UIWebView gets angry whenever I include more than two javascript files that contain jQuery stuff).  Javascript doesn't get on my good side with stuff like this...or maybe I don't get on Javascript's good side with this...well, it's annoying -_-;

*EDIT*:  I figure I should mention about textOps.js.  It is just a bunch of functions I made, it doesn't mess with jQuery in any way, just uses it (Big long list of function {} that I called from obj-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, turns out the problem was that the jquery.color.js file found its way into the compile sources section of the project instead of the bundle resources.  I thought this problem was gone with XCode 4.3 but apparently I was wrong.